# How do I properly install the libshaderc component to run Vulkan example code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-ndk, vulkan

Whenever I try to build the Vulkan samples in Android Studio, I get the following error:

> Error:error:
>   'C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/libs/gnustl_static/x86/libshaderc.a',
>   needed by
>   '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libvulkan_sample.so',
>   missing and no known rule to make it

I've tried compiling the shaders ahead of time, and following the setup directions, yet I cannot seem to overcome this issue. I have no gnustl-static directory in my libs folder. How do I install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with the same problem, According to: https://developer.android.google.cn/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started.html

In $NDK\sources\third_party\shaderc, excute:

```
..\..\..\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk APP_STL:=gnustl_static APP_ABI=x86 libshaderc_combined
```

will generate libshaderc.a